# Is var db = window.openDatabase && openDatabase(); a good way to avoid errors?

Tags: javascript

Is this a good way to avoid errors?

```
var sql_db = window.openDatabase && openDatabase('table', '1.0', 'description', 4096);
```

It seems to work, but is this a good way to avoid errors if a feature isn't implemented? Later on I'll just check if `sql_db` is `undefined` / `null` / `false`.

Does it work in all browsers, and does it return `undefined`, `null` or `false` if `window.openDatabase` isn't supported?

Please note that this isn't only about `openDatabase` but rather any feature that may not be implemented in all browsers. I'm already doing `window.console && console.log()` and that works fine, but in that case I'm not saving any object to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, although I'd suggest adding the `window.` part after the `&&` as well, just to prevent conflict with any local variables.

If the global variable is not defined, it will return `undefined` - this behaviour is consistent across browsers, however keep in mind that `undefined` is not a reserved word and can theoretically be overwritten. Why someone would do that is beyond me, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely convinced whether this is a good idea for this specific case.

For `console && console.log`, I think it's pretty good, but if you're using it with the `openDatabase` call then maybe not.

Why?

If you have a variable that you use for database calls, `sql_db`, what if it's null? It's going to cause an error. Are you going to prefix every single use with `sql_db &&`? It feels like a kludge and it might not even be possible to always do that.

In a case where you actually will be using the result of the call for something, you probably should just opt for a normal if-else check. This way you can detect the failure early, and the code which depends on the result of that will work more reliably without requiring boilerplate variable checks.